# How can initiate localStorage with multi array

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am loosing a lot of time by trying to modifiy my localstorage.

Initialy I inititate it like this

```
localStorage.setItem('bipme','{"modules": []}');
```

It work, but know I need to have this exemple

```
{
    "modules" : [
        {
            "id" : "0",
            "pseudo" : "Titi",
            "mode" : "gps",
            "perimetre" : "3",
            "distance" : "1",
            "start" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00",
            "refresh" : "08:20:00",
            "last" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "pseudo" : "Toto",
            "mode" : "phone",
            "perimetre" : "10",
            "distance" : "0",
            "start" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00",
            "refresh" : "08:20:00",
            "last" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "pseudo" : "Tete",
            "mode" : "gps",
            "perimetre" : "5",
            "distance" : "5",
            "start" : "2012-08-23 08:00:00",
            "refresh" : "10:20:00",
            "last" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "modulesIndex" : 0,

    "watchPosition" : [
        {
            "id" : "0",
            "pseudo" : "Antoine",
            "phone" : "+41781234567",
            "date" : "2012-05-01 17:20:00"
        },
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "pseudo" : "Barbara",
            "phone" : "+41781234567",
            "date" : "2012-05-27 17:20:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, I tryed this

```
localStorage.setItem('bipme','{"modules":[]},{"modulesIndex":0},{"watchPosition":[]}');
```

But now I always get this error message

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
[Break On This Error]   

var objJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bipme'));
```

Then now how can I inititate my local storage correctly

Thank

Comment: Oups, I just found:
localStorage.setItem('bipme','{"modules":[],"modulesIndex":0,"watchPosition":[]}');
Is it well corrext?

Answer (score 1):

The design pattern is that, you use JSON stringify to the object to want to store. For example:

```
var objs = {
  modules : [
    {
        "id" : "0",
        "pseudo" : "Titi",
        "mode" : "gps",
        "perimetre" : "3",
        "distance" : "1",
        "start" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00",
        "refresh" : "08:20:00",
        "last" : "2012-09-23 08:00:00"
    }]
};
localStorage.setItem('bipme', JSON.stringify(objs));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple objects there. If that's what you want you need to use square brackets for an array:

```
localStorage.setItem('bipme','{"modules":[]},{"modulesIndex":0},{"watchPosition":[]}');
// Should be:
localStorage.setItem('bipme','[{"modules":[]},{"modulesIndex":0},{"watchPosition":[]}]');
```

If you intend `modulesIndex` etc. to be part of the same object then simply don't close the object:

```
localStorage.setItem('bipme','{"modules":[],"modulesIndex":0,"watchPosition":[]}');
```

Which I believe you already worked out in your comment.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I should check more carefully! (Especially since OP already commented with the correct code). Edited.